# Committing changes to database

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb, commit, oracle-adf

I have an EJB based project and I want to commit the values in the input fields to the database. I dragged the merge method from the data controls and dropped it as a button but there is no effect on clicking on it. I cannot find where is the fault, because I am a beginner, so I will be very grateful if you help me or give me some piece of advice!

Action of the button:

```
<af:button actionListener="#{bindings.mergeEntity.execute}" text="mergeEntity" disabled="#{!bindings.mergeEntity.enabled}" id="b1"/>
```

Code from session bean:

```
private void commitTransaction() 
{ 
    final EntityTransaction entityTransaction = em.getTransaction(); 
    if (!entityTransaction.isActive()) 
    { 
        entityTransaction.begin(); 
    } 
    entityTransaction.commit(); 
}


public <T> T mergeEntity(T entity) 
{ 
    entity = em.merge(entity); 
    commitTransaction(); 
    return entity; 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, show some code to help everyone understand your problem better.

Comment: <af:button actionListener="#{bindings.mergeEntity.execute}" text="mergeEntity"
             disabled="#{!bindings.mergeEntity.enabled}" id="b1"/> - This is the action of the button

Comment: private void commitTransaction() {
        final EntityTransaction entityTransaction = em.getTransaction();
        if (!entityTransaction.isActive()) {
            entityTransaction.begin();
        }
        entityTransaction.commit();
    }

Comment: public <T> T mergeEntity(T entity) {
        entity = em.merge(entity);
        commitTransaction();
        return entity;
    }

Comment: These are the functions which I run from the session bean. However there is no action of commit to the database. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you want to add to a question use the 'Edit' button. I've added in the code for you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! :) I will do it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to piece together the code fragments you posted in the comments, and I see something wrong with your code.

```
public <T> T mergeEntity(T entity) { 
    entity = em.merge(entity); 
    commitTransaction(); 
    return entity; 
}

private void commitTransaction() { 
    final EntityTransaction entityTransaction = em.getTransaction(); 
    if (!entityTransaction.isActive()) { entityTransaction.begin(); 
    } entityTransaction.commit(); 
}
```

You only called `commitTransaction` method after the `merge` operation. Inside your `commitTransition` is the only time when try you start/begin your transaction. That means, your `merge` operation is executed outside the boundaries of your transaction. This is wrong.

It should have been:

```
entityTransaction.begin(); 
entity = em.merge(entity); 
entityTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer!

Comment: No problem. If you deem that this is the correct answer, kindly accept it.